# Determine if two dates falls between two dates

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if two dates falls between another two dates. So for example:

```
date aStart = 20-10-2013
date aEnd   = 30-10-2013
date bStart = 21-10-2013
date bEnd   = 29-10-2013
```

`bStart` and `bEnd` falls between `aStart` and `aEnd`. Currently I have this code, but it fails on some conditions:

```
if(bannerStartDateTime > bannerEndDateTime) {
    alert("Start Date Banner > End Date Banner.");
    return;
}
if(bannerStartDateTime < workOrderCampaignStartDateTime) {
    alert("Start Date Banner < Start Date WO.");
    return;
}
if(bannerEndDateTime < bannerStartDateTime) {
    alert("End Date Banner < Start Date Banner.");
    return;
}
if(bannerEndDateTime > workorderCampaignEndDateTime) {
    alert("End Date Banner > End Date WO.");
    return;
}
```

What's wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the dates? Your syntax in the first code block is not valid JS.

Comment: What variable names are you using? The ones at the top are different to the ones at the bottom - meaning that you are comparing `undefined` with `undefined`.

Comment: The variable that you have declared are not used in comparing purpose. Also compare date by converting string into date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (bStart > aStart && bStart < aEnd && bEnd > aStart && bEnd < aEnd) {
    alert ("bStart-bEnd is between aStart-End");
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd repeat the condition `bEnd < aEnd`. Did you forgot to add some more parentheses?

Comment: One of them was supposed to be bStart.

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with the code?

The statement:

```
date aStart = 20-10-2013
```

is not valid javascript. And:

```
if (bannerStartDateTime > bannerEndDateTime)
```

uses two identifiers that haven't be declared or initialised.

If you mean to convert the string '20-10-2013' to a date, then you need to write a small parser like:

```
function dmyToDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
}
```

Do not be tempted to pass a date string to the Date constructor, as that will call *Date.parse* which is notoriously inconsistent across browsers, even when using the format [specified in *ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

So now your code can be:

```
var bannerStartDateTime = dmyToDate('20-10-2013');
var bannerEndDateTime   = dmyToDate('30-10-2013');
```

and so on. You can then proceed with comparisons using the `<` and `>` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create date variables. Note that string format is 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

```
var aStart = new Date('10/20/2013'),
    aEnd   = new Date('10/30/2013'),
    bStart = new Date('10/21/2013'),
    bEnd   = new Date('10/29/2013');
```

Now you can compare dates using getTime() method

```
if (aStart.getTime() < aEnd.getTime()) {
    $('.msgContainer').append('<div>a-ha</div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LafkE/

Comment: Seems that your date format is entirely different to the OP and you are hoping that parsing a non–standard string (which is entirely implementation dependant) will work reliably. And then tossed in use of a library not tagged or used in the OP. Careful!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct date format and date object in javascript.

```
var aStart = new Date('2013-10-20');
var aEnd   = new Date('2013-10-30');
var bStart = new Date('2013-10-21');
var bEnd   = new Date('2013-10-29');

if ((bStart > aStart && bStart < aEnd) && (bEnd > aStart && bEnd < aEnd)) {
    alert ("bStart and bEnd both are between aStart and aEnd");
}
else if (bStart > aStart && bStart < aEnd) {
    alert ("bStart is between aStart-End");
}
else if (bEnd > aStart && bEnd < aEnd) {
    alert ("bEnd both is between aStart and aEnd");
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X948h/1/)

Comment: `You have to use correct date format`. No, the OP needs to parse the strings. The format you have used will be treated differently in say Chrome to Firefox. Do not leave parsing of Date strings to *Date.parse*.