# Different behaviour of Javascript between Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla

***[based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818673/determine-if-two-dates-falls-between-two-dates) question]***

Based on previous question, I find below code is meet my requirement.

```
if (bannerStartDateTime >= workOrderCampaignStartDateTime 
        && bannerStartDateTime < workorderCampaignEndDateTime 
        && bannerEndDateTime > workOrderCampaignStartDateTime 
        && bannerEndDateTime <= workorderCampaignEndDateTime) { }
else {
    alert ("Banner Start/End Date must between Work Order Campaign Start/End Date.");
    return;
}
```

I tested it on Chrome and it's ok. But, when I tried to test it using Mozilla Firefox, why it's failed? I am using this example:

```
workOrderCampaignStartDateTime  = "2014-07-18 15:40";
workorderCampaignEndDateTime    = "2014-07-18 16:00";
bannerStartDateTime             = "2014-07-18 15:40";
bannerEndDateTime               = "2014-07-18 16:00";
```

It's work in Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I have created an [example](http://codepen.io/nicolasmccurdy/pen/Bexhw?editors=101) for this, and I am getting "true" for the conditional in Safari 6 and the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome. What version of Firefox are you having an issue with? And do you see it on my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this code and it works in my Firefox browser.

Why don't you use javasript Date object, for example:

```
bannerEndDateTime= new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes)
```